# Uniqueness predicate (Discrete mathematics)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

"Every child gets exactly one book"
How do i use predicates, quantifiers and logical connectives to express this statement WITHOUT using the uniqueness symbol?

I found this on Wikipedia but have no idea how to adapt it for this case...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to split $\exists!$ into two parts. In informal proofs, I like "every child gets *at least* one book, and every child gets *at most* one book."

Formally, I prefer "for every child, there *exists* a book $B$ that the child gets, and *for all*  books $B'$,  if the child gets $B'$, then $B' = B$." As in, there aren't any books that the child gets that *aren't* $B$ - if the child gets a book, it has to be $B$.

That's the idea behind the second sentence in the image you linked. They are all equivalent of course - the third is closer to "Every child gets a book *X*, and (forgetting about *X* and starting a new sentence) if the child gets two books *Y* and *Z*, then *Y* and *Z* must be the same book. This is the "at least 1, and at most 1" way of writing it.

Comment: +1. Note to the OP that in the second paragraph we have *nested* quantification: we can't talk about whether $B'=B$ without "still having $B$ around," so we're going to get a sentence of the form $$\forall B(...\wedge \forall B'(...))$$ rather than $$\forall B(...)\wedge\forall B'(...).$$ If you want a formula of the latter form, that's what the approach in the first paragraph does.

Comment: Thanks, Noah. Do you know a good way to emphasize this in written form?

Comment: Actually I was having a silly moment: the first paragraph gives you a sentence of the form $$\forall B(...)\wedge\forall B', B''(...),$$ and this actually isn't any better than the other form.

Comment: Hello, just to clarify here, would your aforementioned B be the y in the formula given? So i would write it as "Let P(X) be x is a child, P(B) be b is  a book" when solving?

Comment: $B$ is $x$, and $B'$ is $y$ - we need a third variable for the child. Say the child is $z$; then you can use $C(z)$ = "z is a child," $K(x)$ = "x is a book," and  $P_z(x)$  or $P(z,x)$ = "z gets x." Our formula is $\forall z, ( C(z) \Rightarrow (\exists x, K(x) \cap P(z,x) \cap (\forall y, (K(y) \cap P(z,y) \Rightarrow  x = y))))$. Does that make more sense? Sorry for all the parentheses - these sentences are really ugly when you actually get them on paper.

Comment: So i would write () = "z is a child," () = "x is a book," and () or (,) = "z gets x. and also K(y) = "y is another book"? So sorry for all the technical qns, it's my first time doing these kind of questions and i really wana get the basic phrasing down right...

Comment: Yes to your definition of $C$. For $K$... $K(-)$ is a predicate, and a predicate is a kind of function: it takes a thing $x$ and returns the sentence "x is a book." So you only need to define $K$ once (by saying something like $K(*)$ = "$*$ is a book" - it doesnt matter what variable you use for $*$ when you define it) and you can use it as much as you want - on $x$, $y$, anything.

For $P$, note that $P(-,-)$ is a function of two variables, while $P_z(-)$ is a bunch of functions of one variable, a different function for every $z$. It's kind of a matter of preference which one you use.

Comment: alright thank you so much! it's a lot clearer now! :)